# How to keep the dictionary alive throughout the session

Tags: python

I have a python class file that is reading all the excel files in a particular folder.

```
class ReadExcel:

    def readexcel(self, filename):

        # Read excel file
        print("reading excel files ... :", filename)
```

My main entry point is from a seperate python file (`Main_entry.py`) from where I am calling this read class.
I need to send a mail at the end of the execution (i.e. when all the file has been read and manipulated). My mail body should contain the information like below-:

```
  File name : File1.xlsx
    Total number of rows= 1
    Number of rows Skipped : 0
    Number of rows inserted  : 0
    Number of rows updated : 1

    File name : File2.xlsx
    Total number of rows= 1
    Number of rows Skipped: 0
    Number of rows inserted  : 0
    Number of rows updated : 1

    File name : File3.xlsx
    Total number of rows= 1
    Number of rows Skipped : 0
    Number of rows inserted : 0
    Number of rows updated : 1
```

How do I store such a information in my dictionary ? Also, how to declare the dict such that the data keeps on appending at every method call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create only one instance of your class `ReadExcel` and append the proper data at the end of each `readexcel` call. E.g.:

```
class ReadExcel:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stats = {}

    def readexcel(self, filename):
        ...
        self.stats[filename] = {"rows": 0, "skipped": 0, ...}
```

and in the `Main_entry.py`

```
...
excel_reader = ReadExcel()
for filename in filenames:
    excel_reader.readexcel(filename)
send_mail(excel_reader.stats)
...
```

If you would provide more info how are you passing the filenames to your script, it might be easier to help.

Comment: Ahh .. single instance  :) Thanks